# The Binary code for the script task is not found. Please open the script in the designer and make sure it builds successfully

Tags: ssis, script-task

I've been trying to solve exercises for Knight's MS SSIS 24 hour trainer.

I have a script task in a package that checks the value of a variable and displays a message box. There are no other components other than this.

When I try to build the Script Task code, it gives the error -

```
One or more errors occurred. 
Project = ST_<GUID#>. File = mscorlib
```

The source code for the script task is as below:

```
        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            if ((int)Dts.Variables["User::intVar"].Value >= 10)
                Dts.Variables["User::strVar"].Value = "Big";
            else
                Dts.Variables["User.strVar"].Value = "Small";
            MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::strVar"].Value.ToString());

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            
        }
```

On running the package, I get the error:

```
The Binary code for the script task is not found. 
Please open the script in the designer and make sure it builds successfully.
```

I've tried pretty much everything I could find on Stack Overflow:

- `Set DelayValidation = True`, Restarted PC, Imported the package to a new project.
- Deleted the entire project and re built it.
- Cleaning the build etc.

Comment: It turns out that, I'm getting this same error for all the Script tasks that I write. Is there any  way to resolve this?

Comment: your else variable is not coded the same, and since it is in quotes it does not compile as an error.

Answer (score 1):

As KeithL noted,

- change this: `Dts.Variables["User.strVar"].Value = "Small";`
- to this:     `Dts.Variables["User::strVar"].Value = "Small";`

I'm not sure why your script is not compiling.  I would also check the errors pane and see if there is another issue like a missing reference to System.Windows.Forms